# GetProperties from class in list

Tags: .net, vb.net, interface

I need to load all the properties of some 10 classes for which i'm using a interface to load the classes to a list.

Trying to load as a separate class it works fine as below,

```
 Dim t As Type
 t = GetType(ClassA)
            For Each prop As PropertyInfo In t.GetProperties()
                FieldnameObjects = New FieldnameObjects
                FieldnameObjects.ClassName = prop.DeclaringType.Name.ToString()
                FieldnameObjects.FieldName = prop.DeclaringType.Name.ToString() + "." + prop.Name.ToString()
                FieldnameObjects.FieldNameObj = prop.Name.ToString()
                FieldnameObjects.FieldType = prop.PropertyType.Name.ToString()
                newList.Add(FieldnameObjects)
            Next
```

Where `FieldnameObjects` is a custom class with those 4 fields. But i need to load multiple classes fields and so i tried the code below,

```
Public Interface IClassTypes

    Property Class1() As ClassA
    Property Class2() As ClassB
    Property Class3() As ClassC
    Property Class4() As ClassD

End Interface
```

When i tried to load the properties from the above list it didn't work well.

Tried something like,

```
 Dim t As Type
 t = GetType(IClassTypes.Class1)
```

Is there any way that i can load some classes in a list and loop to get all the fields at once instead of loading it separately?

Something like this,

```
For Each prop As object In LisfOfClasses()
    Dim t As Type
    t = GetType(prop.Class1)
  For Each prop As PropertyInfo In t.GetProperties()
     //Code here
  Next
Next
```

Comment: define "didn't work well"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're passing as `ListOfClasses` but `prop.Class1` looks odd. Using a list of the actual types will make it easier.

Comment: @Gusman Updated

Comment: @stuartd can that be explained more?

Comment: Something like `Dim listOfTypes As var = New List(Of Type)() {GetType(Class1), GetType(Class2), GetType(Class3), GetType(Class4)}` (autoconveted from C#) and then `For Each t As Type In listOfTypes`